# R - Get average values of steps in line chart

Tags: r

Consider this data

```
#Create the dataframe
values <- c(0, 0, 0, rep(30, 59), 0, rep(14, 20), 0, rep(24, 63), 0, 0 )
df <- data.frame(Samples = 1:length(values), Value = values)
#Add noise
set.seed(123)  # for reproducibility
noise <- rnorm(length(values), mean = 0, sd = 1)  # Generating random noise
df$Value <- df$Value + noise  # Adding noise to the values`

#Plot
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = df, aes(y = Value, x = Samples)) +
geom_line(color = "red", size = 1)
```

[image]

I would like to get the mean and SD of each step. They can be of different widths and heights.

I tried calculating the rolling standard deviation then detect the maximas then measure average values between maximas of SD but due to the difference in length of the steps I was unsuccesfull to accuratelly detect the start and end of steps.

Comment: Thanks, for this test data, your suggestion makes 7 steps (the 3 obvious ones plus 2 at the beginning and 2 at the end). How would you suggest dealing with that, as every single value below your threshold becomes a step?

Comment: I've fleshed out in an answer below to trigger a new step whenever we go from a flagged value to an unflagged one.